# Open Safari from my Today Extension (widget) within my app

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I have a Today Extension with a text field. I want to use the contents of the text field as a URL to open a browser within my app.

This is my TodayViewController.swift for my widget

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import NotificationCenter

// This extension to remove the white spaces from what pasteed   
extension String {
func replace(string:String, replacement:String) -> String {
    return self.replacingOccurrences(of: string, with: replacement,             
options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
}

func removeWhitespace() -> String {
    return self.replace(string: " ", replacement: "")
}
}


class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {

var clearNumber: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


func widgetPerformUpdate(completionHandler: (@escaping (NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
    // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

    // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
    // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
    // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

    completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.newData)
}



@IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!

@IBAction func clearNumber(_ sender: Any) {

    if textBox.hasText == true {
        textBox.text = ""
    }else{
        return
    }

}

@IBAction func pasteNumber(_ sender: Any) {

    if let myString = UIPasteboard.general.string {
        let pasteNumber = myString.removeWhitespace()
        textBox.insertText(pasteNumber)
    }else{
        return
    }
}

@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAppUrl = URL(string: "main-screen:")!
    extensionContext?.open(myAppUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
        if (!success) {
            print("error: failed to open app from Today Extension")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You must use deep linking.

Comment: I’m new in Swift.. can you provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use @Giuseppe_Lanza solution and parse url that you receive from Today Extension Widget. However, I would show an example where your url have a static components and looking for a path such as `https:/www.apple.com/homepod` or `https:/www.apple.com/iphone` based on user's input in the textField:

1- URL Scheme: `myAppName`

2- Add this to open your app with widget

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {
    openApp(widgetText: "\(textBox.text!)")
}

func openApp(widgetText:String)    {

    let str = "myAppName://https://www.apple.com/\(widgetText)"
    let url = URL(string: str)!
    if textBox.hasText == true  {

        extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: { (success) in
            if (!success) {
                print("error:  ")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

3- AppDelegate

Define a variable and pass received url to webViewController, will parse url there.

```
open var receivedUrl:URL?

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool{

    receivedUrl = url
    //You need to alter this navigation to match your app requirement so that you get a reference to your previous view..
    window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDeepLink", sender: nil)
}
```

> Make sure to make add an identifier for this segue under the attributes
>   inspector as `toDeepLink`.

4- WebView & parsing url
Now you can get the receivedUrl like this

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    print("receivedUrl \(myAppDelegate.receivedUrl!)")
    //url Parsing & getting rid off urlScheme
    let urlToLoad = URL(string: "\(myAppDelegate.receivedUrl!.host! + ":" + myAppDelegate.receivedUrl!.path)")!
    print(urlToLoad)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlToLoad)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
}
```

Else, you need to parse it in a proper way like dictionary to assign dynamic values to respective keys in your dictionary and hence to your url or append `"?"` to your `urlToLoad` just before you attempt to append url.query as I did in the webView controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using deep linking.

First [define a custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls)

Once your app responds to the custom scheme `my-app://` you can open your app from your todayViewController.

```
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let myAppUrl = URL(string: "my-app://openurl/\(yourURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed))")!
    extensionContext?.open(myAppUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
        if (!success) {
            print("error: failed to open app from Today Extension")
        }
    })
}
```

In your app, just like described in the previous link you will have to implement in your app delegate

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
  options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

in this method, the url will be the one you created in your app extension. Meaning it will be `my-app://openurl/{the url with percent escaping}` You will have to parse this url, initialise the view controller that contains the webView and pass the url to be opened.

Comment: I had add a custom URL to open app from my widget.. check the last method in my code

Comment: Read the rest of my answer please.

Comment: `let myAppUrl = URL(string: "main-screen:")!` this is not a valid url. As I said, read the rest of my answer

Comment: I want to open the url with safari inside my app using SafariServices , i tried your code but i didn't know how to open it in safari .. i know the safari code is looks like this `let urlString = "https://google.com"
            
            print(urlString)
            
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
                vc.delegate = self
                self.present(vc, animated: true)
` but where i put it ?

Comment: @cs4alhaider As I said, if you read my answer you will find the solution. When you press the button, the code I wrote for the function `goButton` will cause your app to be opened (of course change the app schema from `my-app://` to whichever sceme you decided to use. When your app opens the app delegate method `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
  options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool` will be called. **Here** you must parse the url in parameter, extract the url you wanted to display in safari and start the safari view controller to show the url.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't. I gave you all the info you need. You must just implement that method in your app delegate.