# AppDelegate function not called when open the host application from the Widget (Today Extension)

Tags: ios, swift, widget, url-scheme, today-extension

## Goal

**From Today Extension (Widget) open app and perform different actions according to button tap.**

- target: iOS 10

---

## Posts & articles readed

- [Today App Extension Widget Tap To Open Containing App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019820/today-app-extension-widget-tap-to-open-containing-app)
- [Open Safari from my Today Extension (widget) within my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401758/open-safari-from-my-today-extension-widget-within-my-app)
- http://atinyfish.com/2014/06/26/adding-a-url-scheme-to-your-app
- https://www.raywenderlich.com/150953/today-extension-tutorial-getting-started
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls

---

## Already done

#### Create URLScheme

**Target/MyApp/Info/URLTypes**

- URLType **identifier** = com.myCompany.MyAppName
- URLType **URLSchemes** = MyAppName
- URLType **role** = Viewer

---

#### Open host application from Widget

**TodayViewController (Widget)**

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let url = URL(string: "MyAppName://")!

  extensionContext?.open(url) { isSuccess in
    switch isSuccess {
    case true: print("Open URL Success") // It print when opening app
    case false: print("Open URL Failed")
    }
  }
}
```

The button works well when tapped. The Host application is launched.

---

#### Delegate func application(_:open:options:) not called

**AppDelegate (Host Application)**

```
// This delegate function is never called when the host application launches
func application(_ app: UIApplication, // breakpoint doesn't trigger
               open url: URL,
               options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool { 

  print("FUNCTION CALLED ") // Never print

  return true
}
```

This delegate function is never called when the host Application opens from button tap in the Widget. How can my app run some code when the application is opened from the widget.
I tried using some other methods but they are deprecated.

I continue searching and it looks like that no `AppDelegate` function can be call when the widget open the host application because all the other methods like `applicationWillEnterForeground` is not called when the application lauches.

I tried on a real device but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

Goto your app target then info -> URL Types -> add a URL Scheme

in your TodayViewController paste the following code

```
self.extensionContext?.open(URL(string: "Your URL Scheme identifier")!, completionHandler: nil)
```